Exercise regarding projective space $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$
Consider the set $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus{0}$ and define the following equivalence relation on it:
$x \sim y$ if there exists $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $y=zx$.
Let $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ denote the space of equivalence classes endowed with the quotient topology.
Define the map $q: \mathbb{C}^n\setminus{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, $x \mapsto [x]$.
Consider $S^{2n-1}$ to be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $\overline{q}:=q_{|S^{2n-1}}$.
Show that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ are smooth, surjective and that (for $y \in \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$),$\overline{q}^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$ diffeomorphic to $S^1$.
My attempt:
The first problems to appraoch are to show that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ are smooth.
To start, here is the definition of smooth map:
Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a map. We say $f$ is smooth, iff for each point $x \in M$ there are charts $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ and $(V,\psi)$ for $N$ such that $x\in U, f(U)\subset V$ and such that $\psi \circ f\circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth in the usual sense of analysis.
Regarding $q$:
The set $U=\mathbb{C}^n\setminus{0}$ is open and $\phi(z_1,...,z_n):=(z_1,...,z_n)$ a homeomorphism.
One can obtain a finite atlas of $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ by defining $V_i:=\{[x_1,...,x_n]:x_i \neq 0\}$ and $\psi_i([x_1,...,x_n]):=(\frac{x_1}{x_i},...,\frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i},\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},...,\frac{x_{n}}{x_i})$.
Now I need to show that "$\psi \circ q \circ \phi^{-1}$" is smooth.
For that, let $x \in \mathbb{C}\setminus{0}$.
Here comes my frist question:
I somehow need to show that $\psi \circ q \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth. For $\mathbb{C}\setminus{0}$ there is only one chart. But for $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ there are $n$ charts.
Which of the charts do I choose? Am I rigth that I need to show that $\psi_i \circ q \circ \phi^{-1}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$?
(I know in that case this doesn't matter since they all have the same form.)
Now $\psi_i \circ q \circ \phi^{-1}(x_1,...,x_n)=(\frac{x_1}{x_i},...,\frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i},\frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},...,\frac{x_{n}}{x_i})$, which is smooth.
Regarding $\overline{q}$:
We defined $\overline{q}$ to be $q_{|S^{2n-1}}$.
The only difference to $q$ is that instead of $U=\mathbb{C}^n\setminus{0}$, now $U=S^{2n-1}$.
So, $\overline{q}$ is smooth too.
surjective:
Next thing to do, is to show that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ are surjective.
So, let $[y] \in \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$. I have to show that there exists $x \in \mathbb{C}\setminus {0}$ s.t. $q(x)=[y]$.
Now I am somewhat unsure, what I have to do and argue. But here is my try: Since $[y]$ is an equivalence class, there exists (by definition) $x,y \in [y]$ such that $y=zx$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus $q$ is surjective.
Question: Was this approach for the surjectivity of $q$ alright?
And does the same argumentation show that $\overline{q}$ is surjective?
And the last part:
At the moment, I am stuck on showing that $\overline{q}^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is diffeomorphic to $S^1$. Any help would be appreciated.


Yes, smoothness has to be checked in all charts of an atlas. 2. You can't take $U=S^{2n-1}$ as that is not an open chart of $S^{2n-1}$. I suggest a different approach: $\overline{q}$ is the composition of $q$ and the inclusion of the smooth submanifold $S^{2n-1}$, hence smooth. 3. The map $q$ is surjective by definition. Carefully review the definitions until this is clear to you. 4. For $\overline{q}$ to be surjective, you need an additional argument. 5. To understand the preimage $\overline{q}^{-1}(y)$, carefully write down what its elements look like.


@Thorgott First, thank you. Regarding 4, I do not see what additional argument I could use. Regarding 5: If $y \in  \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, then $q^{-1}(y)$ should be the set of all $x,y$ such that $y=xz$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If I now restrict $q$ to $S^{2n-1}$, then I get that $\overline{q}^{-1}(y)$ consists of only two points. Namely, the two points $x,y$ such that $x,y$ can be connected through a line through the origin.

"Show that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ are smooth". This exercise only makes sense if $\mathbb CP^{n-1}$ is given a smooth structure. You define an atlas in your question, but the exercise should be "Give $\mathbb CP^{n-1}$ a smooth structure such that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ become smooth".

"then I get that $\bar q^{-1}(y)$  consists of only two points." No, a two point set is  not diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

@PaulFrost Could you please show me how to give $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ a smooth structure such that $q$ and $\overline{q}$ are smooth?

I know that $\overline{q}^{-1}$ should not consist of only two points. I just wanted to write down what I did. Maybe someone could then explain what was wrong /what would be correct.

Let us first observe that $n = 1$ is a special case since $\mathbb CP^0$ is a single point space (which can be regarded as $0$-dimensional smooth manifold). This case is trivial, so let us assume $n > 1$.
This exercise only makes sense if $\mathbb CP^{n−1}$ is given a smooth structure. Thus the exercise should be

Give $\mathbb CP^{n−1}$ a smooth structure such that $q$ and $\bar q$ become smooth.

Perhaps such a smooth structure was already introduced in your textbook or lecture notes. Then the original exercise is okay.
Anyway, you define an atlas on $\mathbb CP^{n−1}$ having $n$ charts $\psi_i : V_i \to \mathbb C^{n-1} = \mathbb R^{2n-2}$. One must prove that all transition functions are smooth (which is easy). This provides the desired smooth structure.

$q$ is smooth.

You are right, you can take $\phi = id$ and you have to consider all $\psi_i$. You correctly stated that all $\psi_i \circ q$ are smooth.

$\bar q$ is smooth.

The inclusion $i : S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$ is smooth because $S^{2n-1}$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$. Hence $\bar q = q \circ i$ is smooth.

$q$ is surjective.

This is true by definition because the elements of $\mathbb CP^{n−1}$  are eqauivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$. We have $q^{-1}([x]) = \{zx \mid z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \} =  (\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}) \cdot x$. This is the intersection of the one-dimensional linear (complex) subspace $\mathbb C \cdot x $ of $\mathbb C^n$ with $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$, hence a two-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$.

$\bar q$ is surjective.

Let $[x] \in \mathbb CP^{n−1}$. Then $x/\lVert x \rVert \in S^{2n-1}$ and $\bar q(x/\lVert x \rVert ) = [x/\lVert x \rVert] = [x]$ because $x = \lVert x \rVert( x/\lVert x \rVert)$.

$\bar{q}^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$ diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

We have $y = [x]$ with $x \in S^{2n-1}$. Hence $\bar q^{-1}([x]) =q^{-1}([x]) \cap  S^{2n-1} = (x \cdot (\mathbb C \setminus \{0\})) \cap  S^{2n-1}  = \{ x \cdot z \mid z \in (\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}, \lVert x\cdot z \rVert = 1\}$. Since $\lVert x \rVert = 1$, $\lVert x\cdot z \rVert = 1$ is equivalent to $\lVert  z \rVert = 1$ so that
$$\bar q^{-1}([x]) = S^1 \cdot x .$$
Clearly $S^1 \cdot x$ is a one-dimensional smooth submanifold $S^{2n-1}$.
